# Is there a method to determine the sources that are used in a model in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder

I have a model that I have had to go through to model parameters in order to create a geoprocessing service.  Is there a way to check all sources that are being used in the model via python?  I am attempting to publish a geoprocessing Service, however one of my sources is not registered with server which prevents my service from being published.

Comment: I think if you export the ModelBuilder to a Python script, the sources will all be listed somewhere in the resulting file. (I wouldn't recommend trying to _run_ Python generated automatically by ModelBuilder, but if you're just looking through to find data sources, no problem.)

Comment: That's a great idea, and it works.

Comment: Found the error in my model, its still proving easier to update the soruce via Python, is there a method to import a python script to a model?

Comment: No. You can include a python script as a tool within a model, but not directly go from Python to ModelBuilder. (And you _CAN_ run the ModelBuilder-generated script in Python, but that is prone to problems because ModelBuilder just doesn't write very nice Python and may include ModelBuilder-only tools...)

Answer (score 2):

If you export the ModelBuilder to a Python script, the sources will all be listed somewhere in the resulting file.

(I don't recommend trying to *run* Python generated automatically by ModelBuilder, but it will quickly show you all the data sources the model/script is using.)